# How to change background color randomly on on window load event up to the background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image with a `body` HTML tag, my code is as follows:

CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:linear-gradient(
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ), url(../img/imahe-1.jpg);
}
```

It is working, and I need the same things, but the color should change randomly when page is loaded (window load function).in body tag there would be a background-image.and color would be with opacity (overlay).it is working with CSS method.but i need to change color randomly (overlay color) not image.

Thank you advance.

Comment: Not sure how that's a duplicate of this, unless you don't actually read this question.  The link shows how to generate a hex string for a random colour.  This question is (sort of) about that **_AND_** how to implement the random colour in a gradient background.  That is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: It goes against the spirit of Stack Overflow and reinforces all the statements about how new users get treated here, when people simply vote to close by linking an unhelpful question as a duplicate.  The question is answered below, for this asker and all the others that follow.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a random gradient background every time it's run...

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
  return "#" + ("000000" + hex.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}

$(function() {
  var col1 = getRandomColor();
  var col2 = getRandomColor();
  $("body").css("background", "linear-gradient(" + col1 + "," + col2 + ")");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can ignore the css in this example.  It's only required to make the snippet work.

Comment: Thank you @Archer ..!! this is the actual example what i want to do..[example here](http://social.dbrqx.com/). `background` and `opacity` also..which will be on load event.

Comment: You can simply add them to the background value applied in the function above, which will already run at load - `$(function() {...});` is a document.ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link Serge K posted in the comments you could do the following:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
  return "#" + ("000000" + hex.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.background = getRandomColor();
```